# Что считать абсурдным?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Я хочу посоветоваться. Как-то (довольно давно уже) попался мне на глаза сей шедевр. Сразу оговорюсь, что автору не 9 и даже не 11, а целых 17 лет. Я выложила избранные перлы из него на сообщество по русскому языку и сообщество, посвященное абсурдным фанфикам. В итоге в первом случае мне заявили: "Талант надо поощрять, а не гнобить", а во втором вообще заявили, что опус не достаточно абсурден для этого сообщества.
Други, я чего-то не понимаю в этой жизни или мир сошел с ума?
И, собственно, опус: http://fanfic.mybb.ru/viewtopic.php?id=471

Comment: А Вы смотрели советский фильм 1964 года "Жаворонок"? Там изображена достаточно фантастическая ситуация. Наши военнопленные бегут с полигона в Германии на Т-34. Проскакивают несколько городков, но в одном останавливаются, и командир говорит товарищу : "Сходи за пивком, а то в горле пересохло..." Танкист заходит в пивную, где испуганные горожане, в том числе военные, жмутся и мнутся, а в следующем кадре беглецы довольно хохочут и пьют немецое пиво. Не может быть?! Да ведь на то и кино, что в нем показывается невозможное в реальности.
Фанфики - для любителей фанфиков, пусть их играются...

Comment: Дело ж даже не в сюжете! Дело в абсолютном незнании хоть чего-то хоть о чем-то, о шедевральном построении фраз, ошибках и прочем.

Comment: >Дело в абсолютном незнании хоть чего-то хоть о чем-то, о шедевральном построении фраз, ошибках и прочем.  
  
Да то-то и оно. Сам по себе жанр "альтернативной истории" вполне себе имеет право на существование. Но работать в нем имеет смысл тем, кто знает и понимает историю "неальтернативную". Иначе это ерничанье Митрофанушки.

Comment: Да вот, @Чукча-писатель, шедевральная фраза во всей красе (из советской прозы) :  
>Возле баркаса, хлюпнув, схлынула вода, и двухаршинный, словно слитый из красной меди, **сазан со стоном прыгнул вверх**, сдвоив по воде изогнутым лопушистым хвостом.

И редакторы, ничуть не задумавшись, пропускают *этакое* в печать... У нас что, рыбы уже стонать могут??

Comment: Могут. 
При всей моем более чем неоднозначном отношении к автору здесь ляпа я не вижу.

Comment: То есть здесь метафора присутствует?

Comment: Не знаю, что здесь присутствует, может просто недомыслие, но звук выдергиваемой из воды крупной рыбы мне знаком. Похож ли он на стон - это уж кто как слышит.  
Все это безотносительно к Шолохову, историю с крюковским протографом здесь поднимать не хочу, хотя она-то может объяснить любой ляп через неверное прочтение первоисточника.

Comment: Кстати, меня в этой фразе куда больше забавляет слово "сдвоил". Это как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меня хватило ровно на пол-абзаца. 
Что касается всякого рода сообществ, то отношение у меня к ним в общем-то однозначное. 
Ничего толкового там нет и быть не может. 
Они для личного общения и удовлетворения потребностей в самоутверждении.

Comment: Ну, там, скорее, справочное сообщество. Там действительно много толкового (оно не для общения) и есть раздел таких вот перлов. Но, когда об ЭТОМ сказали, что это "талант, который надо развивать", я, честно говоря, не знала даже, что на это ответить.))))

Comment: А это серьезно сказали? Смайлика не было?

Answer (score 2):

Твёрдо убеждён, что подобное упрощённое видение мира вызвано обилием примитивных сериалов.

У меня дочка все сериалы пересмотрела, сейчас смотрит что-то про зомби, это просто ужасно. Шаблонные сценарии, множество ляпов и полный примитив порождают подобные "фанфики".